# What plane is this? It’s hanging at a bar in Colorado

Tags: aircraft-identification

Consider:

[image: Plane hanging at a bar in Colorado]

I can’t seem to find out what plane this is. I keep digging online for small twins with twin tips. It has an Air Force emblem on the sign, but I can’t find anything on it.

Comment: Also note the straight tip-tanks. Pre 1962 I believe. Tip tanks (50 gallons each) were canted after that.

Comment: Did you do a Google image search?

Comment: 310. I did my multi rating in one of those. Great aircraft.

Answer (score 27):

If you look up the bar's website you get a little more detail about this aircraft:

[Source: Hangar 101 Billiards](https://hangar101billiards.com/our-story/)

> The Cessna 310 over the bowling alley is a navy trainer aircraft. It trained some of the finest pilots in the U.S. Navy.

There are more pictures of the aircraft (and others on display) on the website:

[image]

Comment: Am I the only person who feels like they would be distracted trying to bowl with that thing in the way?

Comment: @Michael You and I have very different bowling techniques if that'd be in your way

Comment: What is distracting about a hanging airplane? the word hanging makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: It is a matter of perspective(?).

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I'd have trouble not hitting the airplane. I'm that bad at bowling.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like a U-3 (military Cessna 310).

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. Cant find any pictures with any with 3 blades on each side. Thank you!

Comment: Look up Sky King on Youtube.  He flew a '57 310B with the square tail in most of the later episodes.  The 3 blade props could easily be a later retrofit.